# Roots of a summation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, roots, binomial-theorem

I'm trying to solve an equation:
$$\sum_{n=0}^b \left(\left(\frac{a+xn}{b}\right)\binom{b}{n}(-x)^{b-n}\right)=0$$
Where a and b are constants.
I thought of solving it by using the binomial theorem. As you can see, the equation is very similar to the binomial expansion:
$$\sum_{n=0}^b \left(\binom{b}{n}(-x)^{b-n}\right)=(1-x)^b$$
I was wondering if there was a way to somehow separate the $\left(\frac{a+xn}{b}\right)$ from the summation to solve the equation.

Comment: How about $$\sum_{n=0}^b \left(\frac{a}{b}\binom{b}{n}(-x)^{b-n}\right) + \sum_{n=0}^b \left(\frac{nx}{b}\binom{b}{n}(-x)^{b-n}\right)=0$$

Comment: Hint: $(a + nx)(-x)^{n-b} = (a+bx + x^2\frac{\partial}{\partial x})(-x)^{n-b}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two sums that you need are
$f_b(x)
=\sum_{n=0}^b \binom{n}{b}x^n
$
and
$g_b(x)
=\sum_{n=0}^b n\binom{n}{b}x^n
$.
Your sum can be written
in terms of these.

The first you should know
from the binomial theorem.

For the second,

$\begin{array}\\
f_b'(x)
&=\sum_{n=0}^b \binom{n}{b}(x^n)'\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^b \binom{n}{b}nx^{n-1}\\
&=\frac1{x}\sum_{n=0}^b \binom{n}{b}nx^{n}\\
&=\frac1{x}g_b(x)\\
\end{array}
$

so
$g_b(x)
=xf_b'(x)
$

and this gives you $g$.